# ISO 8601 date-time format combining 'Z' and offset of '+0000'

Tags: time, datetime-format, iso8601, timezone-offset

I'm playing with date-time format from ISO 8601. I have this pattern:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ'Z'"
```

and the output is:

```
"2015-11-17T00:00:00+0000Z"
```

My question is if the output is ok, if is possible to have in a date `+0000` and `Z` taking in account both has the same meaning time zone offset/id. Thanks in advance for clarification =)

Comment: @BasilBourque I don think so needs clarification, it is clear, it asks if that date format is ok "2015-11-17T00:00:00+0000Z" =)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## No, not OK

No, the `Z` *is* an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). So it should *not* be combined redundantly with a numerical offset of `+00:00` or `+0000`.

### ISO 8601

While I do not have access to a paid copy of the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) spec, the [Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) clearly states that the `Z` must follow the time-of-day:

> …add a Z directly after the time without a space.

### IETF RFC 3339

The freely-available [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339), a profile of ISO 8601, defines a `Z` as being attached to a time-of-day:

> A suffix … applied to a time …

The RFC also states with formal [ABNF notation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) that we should use *either* a `Z` or a number. In ABNF, the slash (SOLIDUS) means “or” (exclusive ‘or’), while the pair of square brackets means “optional”.

> time-numoffset    = ("+" / "-") time-hour [[":"] time-minute]
>
> time-zone         = "Z" / time-numoffset

Furthermore, [section 5.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.4) of the spec specifically recommends *against* including redundant information.

## Java

The modern *java.time* classes built into Java use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats by default when parsing/generating strings. See [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

### Parsing text input

With `Z`:

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2019-01-23T12:34:56.123456789Z" ) ;
```

With `+00:00`:

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2019-01-23T12:34:56.123456789+00:00" ) ;
```

### Generating text output

To create a string with the `Z`, simply call `Instant::toString`.

```
String output = Instant.now().toString() ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC, then generate text representing that value in standard ISO 8601 using the `Z` offset-indicator.
```

> 2019-05-22T21:00:52.214709Z

To create a string with the `00:00`, call `OffsetDateTime::format`. Generate text using a `DateTimeFormatter` with a formatting pattern you define.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxxx" ) ;
String output = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ).format( f ) ;
```

> 2019-05-22T21:00:52.319076+00:00

### Truncating

You may want to truncate any microseconds or nanoseconds.

```
Instant
.now()
.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MILLIS )
.toString()
```

> 2019-05-22T21:11:28.970Z

…and…

```
OffsetDateTime
.now( ZoneOffset.UTC )
.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MILLIS )
.format( 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxxx" )
)
```

> 2019-05-22T21:11:29.078+00:00

See this [code running live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/9w8zwa).

Comment: in Java: `final String DATE_FORMAT_ISO_8601 = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";`

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere No, do not bury the `Z` inside a pair of single-quote marks. This turns the `Z` into a string literal, mere decoration, rather than a meaningful pattern code.

Comment: I'm currently working on a crypto-coin project and the API spec requires the "Z" at the end, instead of the "+0000". https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/?javascript#time

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere Fine, but that is no reason to define a broken formatting pattern. The `Z` in a formatting pattern should *never* be inside single-quotes. I will edit the Answer to show the easy way to get the `Z` to appear: `Instant.now().toString()`. You may want to truncate any microseconds/nanoseconds: `Instant.now().truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MILLIS ).toString()`

Comment: @BasilBourque so do we need to use, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ+0400' to represent it is new york timestamp?

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal Reread the first sentence of my Answer. The `Z` in a `DateTimeFormatter` formatting pattern is a code indicating you want to generate text representing the offset. So then appending a hard-coded `+0400` is redundant, is a contradiction of the `Z`, and is invalid syntax. So I am not really sure what you meant to ask. And for a New York time zone (`America/New_York`), you would be using a time zone with a `ZonedDateTime` object rather than an offset. Ex: `ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ).toString()`.

Comment: got it, thanks @BasilBourque. so the timestamp would look like `"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZZ-04:00"`