# unable to parse String to ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, zoneddatetime

I tried to parse a string of datetime "20201211100938Z+0000" but I am not able to find a right DateTimeFormatter to be used for this. For all the trials, I am getting some kind of parse exceptions. Can you please help with a right DateTimeFormatter to be used in the

```
ZonedDateTime.parse("20201211100938Z+0000", **formatter**)
```

Comment: can you show us the formatter please ?

Comment: @YCF_L
Following is a formatter I tried. Multiple formatters I tried, but not able to find the right one. 
`DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddhhmmssXX");`

Comment: The string you are trying to parse seems wrong. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35869074/2738151) about the combination of `Z` and `+0000`.

Comment: @HernánAlarcón

That is the string I am getting from another upstream application. I cannot change that format. That is why I was looking for a help in getting this parsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following. You need to treat the existing Z in the date as a literal.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt= ZonedDateTime.parse("20201211100938Z+0000",
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss'Z'Z"));
System.out.println(zdt);
System.out.println(zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss'Z'Z"));
```

Prints

```
2020-12-11T10:09:38Z
20201211100938Z+0000
```