# How to serialise Date of request body in a specific format in Feign Client?

Tags: java, spring-boot, serialization, encoding, spring-cloud-feign

I try to send a request to a third party api using feign client. When I check the request body, it looks like below:

```json
{
  "requestTime": "2023-06-07T12:18:00.916+00:00"
}
```

but the api only accept the date format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'mm:hh:ss.SSSZ`, so the valid request body would be something similar below:

```json
{
  "requestTime": "2023-06-17T14:53:47.402Z"
}
```

How do I config the serialisation of date format in Feign Client?

My codes:

```java
@FeignClient(value = "myfeign", url = "https://myfeign.com/")
public interface MyFeignClient {

    @PostMapping(value = "/myfeign/", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    MyResponse sendRequest(MyRequest request);
}
```

And `MyRequest` is generated from openapi-generator.

```java
public class MyRequest {
   @JsonProperty("requestTime")
   @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
   private Date requestTime;
   // getter...
}
```

Edit: My approach below doesn't work as the request object still use `"2023-06-07T12:18:00.916+00:00"` format.

```java
public class MyFeignConfig {

    @Bean
    public Encoder feignEncoder() {
        HttpMessageConverter<Object> jacksonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapper());

        HttpMessageConverters httpMessageConverters = new HttpMessageConverters(jacksonConverter);
        ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters> objectFactory = () -> httpMessageConverters;


        return new SpringEncoder(objectFactory);
    }

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'mm:hh:ss.SSSZ";
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat((DATE_FORMAT));
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setDateFormat(dateFormat);
    }
```

add configuration in the client

```java
@FeignClient(value = "myfeign", url = "https://myfeign.com/",  configuration = "MyFeignConfig.class")
public interface MyFeignClient {

    @PostMapping(value = "/myfeign/", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    MyResponse sendRequest(MyRequest request);
}
```

Comment: did you try with something like @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm z") ?
i learned that sometime strange things works..

Comment: I don't use this api but maybe something like `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = ...`

Comment: @Goikiu, I cannot change the MyRequest Object.

Comment: @g00se, I cannot change the MyRequest Object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My approach below doesn't work

Without knowing what "doesn't work" means, I can at least see that [`jackson/databind` `ObjectMapper#setDateFormat()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#setDateFormat-java.text.DateFormat-) takes a [`DateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html?is-external=true) class, not a string.

See also "[Jackson Date](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-dates)" by [Eugen Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/about/) for illustration.

Something like:

```java
public class MyFeignConfig {

    private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";

    @Bean
    public Encoder feignEncoder() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = objectMapper();
        HttpMessageConverter<Object> jacksonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapper);

        HttpMessageConverters httpMessageConverters = new HttpMessageConverters(jacksonConverter);
        ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters> objectFactory = () -> httpMessageConverters;

        return new SpringEncoder(objectFactory);
    }

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setDateFormat(dateFormat);
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

Note the date format string: it is changed to `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"`, because `mm` and `hh` in Java's date format stands for minute and hour in am/pm, you should use `HH` for hour of day (0 - 23) and `mm` for minute in hour.

As noted by [Olivier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12763954/olivier) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76432777/how-to-serialise-date-of-request-body-in-a-specific-format-in-feign-client/76447607#comment134801234_76447607), `'Z'` will output a literal `Z` in the output, as opposed to Z, which prints the [timezone offset to UTC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), as illustrated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35856437/6309).

Then, you apply this configuration to your feign client:

```java
@FeignClient(value = "myfeign", url = "https://myfeign.com/", configuration = MyFeignConfig.class)
public interface MyFeignClient {

    @PostMapping(value = "/myfeign/", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    MyResponse sendRequest(MyRequest request);
}
```

This should configure your Feign client to use your custom ObjectMapper which uses the correct date format. The time zone has been set to UTC in the `SimpleDateFormat` to make sure the serialized date string ends with a `Z` to indicate UTC.

---

> I updated my approach for missing codes. So, I don't understand why my approach still send as "`2023-06-07T12:18:00.916+00:00`".
> What I expected actually is fail to serialize and throw error. Could you explain this to me?

When Spring Boot starts up, it creates a default `ObjectMapper` bean with standard configuration. If you define an `ObjectMapper` in your own configuration (like you could have done in `MyFeignConfig`), Spring does not replace the default one - it simply adds your `ObjectMapper` as another bean.

Since `SpringEncoder` (the class used by Feign for encoding requests) is configured to use an `ObjectMapper` bean, it will inject one from the application context. But if there are multiple `ObjectMapper` beans, the one it gets might not be the one you have configured. This could explain why you are seeing the default date format instead of the one you have set.

One way to ensure your `ObjectMapper` is used is by marking it as `@Primary`. This tells Spring that when multiple beans of the same type are present, this is the one that should be used.

You can update your `MyFeignConfig` class as follows:

```java
public class MyFeignConfig {

    private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setDateFormat(dateFormat);
        return objectMapper;
    }

    @Bean
    public Encoder feignEncoder(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        HttpMessageConverter<Object> jacksonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapper);

        HttpMessageConverters httpMessageConverters = new HttpMessageConverters(jacksonConverter);
        ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters> objectFactory = () -> httpMessageConverters;

        return new SpringEncoder(objectFactory);
    }
}
```

Note that the `ObjectMapper` bean is now annotated with `@Primary`, and the `feignEncoder` method now takes an `ObjectMapper` parameter. This ensures that the `ObjectMapper` used in `feignEncoder` is the same one that you have configured.
See "[Spring Boot: Customize the Jackson ObjectMapper](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-customize-jackson-objectmapper#1-objectmapper)", again by [Eugen Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/about/).

Warning: Marking a bean as `@Primary` will affect all places in your application where an `ObjectMapper` bean is injected.
If you want to use different `ObjectMapper` configurations in different parts of your application, you will need a different solution. In that case, you might need to create a custom `Encoder` or `Decoder` that uses your specific `ObjectMapper`, or use Feign's request/response interceptors to manually handle the serialization.

---

For more, the [Spring Cloud OpenFeign documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/docs/current/reference/html/) explains how you can take full control of the feign client by declaring additional configuration using `@FeignClient`. In this case, the client is composed from the components already in `FeignClientsConfiguration` together with any in your custom configuration (where the latter will override the former). The `FeignClientsConfiguration` class provides default beans for feign including `feign.Encoder` which is `SpringEncoder` by default.

If there are multiple `ObjectMapper` beans in the application context, the one that `SpringEncoder` (used by Feign for encoding requests) gets might not be the one you have configured. This situation might arise if the custom configuration is included in a `@ComponentScan` that would otherwise include this configuration as it will become the default source for `feign.Decoder`, `feign.Encoder`, `feign.Contract`, etc., when specified. This can be avoided by putting it in a separate, non-overlapping package from any `@ComponentScan` or `@SpringBootApplication`, or it can be explicitly excluded in `@ComponentScan`.

From the [source code of `JacksonEncoder`](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/master/jackson/src/main/java/feign/jackson/JacksonEncoder.java#L31-L46), which is an implementation of `Encoder`, you can see that an `ObjectMapper` is used to encode the request body. It uses the `ObjectMapper` to write the object as bytes and sets it as the body of the `RequestTemplate`. This suggests that `ObjectMapper` plays an important role in the encoding process, and if the `ObjectMapper` is not properly configured, it can lead to unexpected results, such as the one you are experiencing.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my approach for missing codes. So, I don't understand why my approach still send as `"2023-06-07T12:18:00.916+00:00"`. What I expected actually is fail to serialise and throw error. Could you explain this to me?

Comment: Your codes works well and I will accept it later to see if there is any better answer.

Comment: @ikhvjs Why would it throw an error? Your pattern is valid. Just not the one you wanted.

Comment: @Olivier if the parrern is valid, why didn’t it send as the pattern defined? It still send as the the format like 2023-06-07T12:18:00.916+00:00

Comment: @ikhvjs Your pattern uses `Z` (which outputs the timezone), not `'Z'` (which is a literal Z).

Comment: @VonC *"If you define an ObjectMapper in your own configuration (like you have done in MyFeignConfig)"* No `ObjectMapper` bean is added to the configuration (the `objectMapper()` method is not annotated with `@Bean`).

Comment: @Olivier True. In that case, a good old debug breakpoint might be needed inside the `feignEncoder` method and to inspect the `ObjectMapper`, checking if it has the expected date format.

Comment: @Olivier, Thanks for clarification of the Z in the date formate. I understand it now.

Comment: @VonC, Oliver already answer my question. Thanks!

Comment: @ikhvjs Good point.  I have included Olivier's comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

To configure the serialization of the date format in Feign Client, you can follow these steps:

Create a configuration class, let's call it FeignConfig, and annotate it with @Configuration.

```
@Configuration
public class FeignConfig {
    // Configuration code will go here
}
```

Define a bean for the ObjectMapper in the FeignConfig class. This bean will be responsible for configuring the date format serialization.

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.setDateFormat(dateFormat);
    
    return objectMapper;
}
```

Here, we're setting the desired date format and ensuring that it uses the UTC time zone.

Create a bean for the Encoder in the FeignConfig class. This bean will use the customized ObjectMapper for serialization.

```
@Bean
public Encoder feignEncoder() {
    HttpMessageConverter<Object> jacksonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapper());

    return new SpringEncoder(() -> new HttpMessageConverters(jacksonConverter));
}
Apply the FeignConfig to your Feign client by specifying the configuration attribute in the @FeignClient annotation.
@FeignClient(value = "myfeign", url = "https://myfeign.com/", configuration = FeignConfig.class)
public interface MyFeignClient {
    // Feign client methods
}
```

By doing this, the Feign client will use the customized ObjectMapper with the specified date format for serialization, ensuring that the request body is formatted correctly before sending the request to the third-party API.